# Class displays despite CSS set to display: none

Tags: html, css, display

In the code below is CSS styled so that the class "crash" is set to not display. The display property works with the other classes I have adjusted but for this crash class nothing is affected. If I pair the crash class with the other classes it is hidden but separate it's as if the code is commented out. How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<img id = "first" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash1.jpg" alt = "A picture you can't see">

<img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash2.jpg" alt = "Another picture you can't see">

<img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash3.jpg" alt = "You must be blind">

<img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash4.jpg" alt = "Or we're not linking up">

<img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash5.jpg" alt = "Still checkin?">
```

CSS:

```
.crash {
  display: none;
}

.Slideshow1 {
  display: none;
}

.DT, .skate, .Gikondo_cold {
  display: none;
  width: 21%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

Comment: The Developer Tools (F12 in most browser) is **very** powerful when it comes to diagnosing these kinds of problems. You can inspect elements and see what styles are in effect and what, if anything, is over riding them.

Comment: Also note that the code you have given us works : https://jsfiddle.net/uqjzvf2g/ . It makes it easier for us to help you if you provide us a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your complete style sheet, I have the feeling you have your display:none rule is being overwritten by another rule further down the stylesheet. Something likely has a display: block rule on these elements which is taking priority.

CSS Style sheets work in a cascading fashion - rules set lower in the style sheet will be given priority over rules higher in the sheet.

As an experiment, try placing your rule:

```
.crash {
  display: none;
}
```

at the very bottom of your stylesheet, and see if that corrects your issue. If it fixes the problem, you can then re-order your stylesheet so that this rule is in a more logical hierarchy.

Comment: This worked... There is no counter CSS in later in the style sheet. The only other displays that show are selected with id's. I don't got clout on here but I know enough CSS to figure out what would clash but there's nothing.